# ContextMenu integration with jQuery FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-contextmenu

I'm using Adam Shaw's `FullCalendar` control along with jQuery. I would like to add a context menu to events and days. I was able to achieve so by using [Martin Wendt's Context Menu control](http://wwwendt.de/tech/demo/jquery-contextmenu/jquery.ui-contextmenu.js). My code for registering the menu on events looks like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // Other arguments
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            var originalClass = element[0].className;
            element[0].className = originalClass + ' hasmenu';
        },
        dayRender: function (day, cell) {
            var originalClass = cell[0].className;
            cell[0].className = originalClass + ' hasmenu';
    });
});
```

I'm essentially adding a class called `hasmenu` to each event and day in the calendar.

```
$(document).contextmenu({
    delegate: ".hasmenu",
    preventContextMenuForPopup: true,
    preventSelect: true,
    menu: [
            {title: "Cut", cmd: "cut", uiIcon: "ui-icon-scissors"},
            {title: "Copy", cmd: "copy", uiIcon: "ui-icon-copy"},
            {title: "Paste", cmd: "paste", uiIcon: "ui-icon-clipboard", disabled: true },
        ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
            // Logic for handing the selected option
    },
    beforeOpen: function(event, ui) {
            // Things to happen right before the menu pops up
    }
});
```

The problem with this is that the menu appears behind the calendar control. I believe this is because calendar events have a few other classes assigned to them and adding a `hasmenu` class is messing with those. When I set a breakpoint in VS, it says the event has these classes:

```
"fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-draggable fc-event-start fc-event-end hasmenu"
```

And this is how it looks on the page:

[image]

I tried temporarily setting the event class to just `hasmenu` while the popup was open but that obviously changed the view entirely. Is there a way to force the menu to be on top of all other elements? Is there a "bring to front" method? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `z-index` ?

Comment: Hmm I can't import some of the scripts since they're on my computer. jsfiddler keeps complaining.

Comment: @feitla How would I do that?

Comment: @feitla Ah. On the CSS. It worked. Please post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjusting the `z-index` will probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

Adjust the `z-index` in the `beforeOpen` event

```
beforeOpen: function (event, ui) {      
    ui.menu.zIndex($(event.target).zIndex() + 1);
}
```

please see: https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu/issues/55

Answer (score 1):

This helps to get resolve your issue:

```
beforeOpen: function (event, ui) {
            var $menu = ui.menu,
                $target = ui.target;
            ui.menu.css('z-index', '10000000');
            // Things to happen right before the menu pops up
        }
```